# Reading data separated by colon per line in Python

Tags: python, text-files

I'm creating a program that has the user's name and their answers to a guess the number game in a database - like format on Python. I have created a text file where all of the users' data is, in the form name : guess. For instance,

```
Dave:23
Adam:12
Jack:13
Dave:25
Adam:34
```

Now, I am trying to re - read the file into Python as a tuple, so I decided to use the line of code below (The real answer is 17):

```
dict(line.split(':', 1) for line in open('guesses.txt'))
```

But this will just hand me back an empty line in the IDLE. 
Why is this not working?

 To make it more simple, I need a tuple that has the user's name and then their guesses.

My dictionary should look like this:

```
{'Dave': 23 25, 'Jack' : 13, 'Adam' : 13 34}
```

Thanks, Delbert.

Comment: Why are Dave and Adam the same people?

Comment: think because you need open('guesses.txt', 'r') (read file)

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke sorry! I didn't think about it!

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke okay thank you for the joke. It is now over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a defaultdict and store values in a list:

```
s="""Dave:23
Adam:12
Jack:13
Dave:25
Adam:34
"""

from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)

for line in s.splitlines():
    name,val = line.split(":")
    d[name].append(int(val))

print(d)
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'Jack': [13], 'Adam': [12, 34], 'Dave': [23, 25]})
```

So for your file just do the same:

```
d = defaultdict(list)
with open('guesses.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        name,val = line.split(":")
        d[name].append(int(val))
```

Your own code should return `{'Jack': '13', 'Dave': '25', 'Adam': '34'}` where the the values for Dave and Adam are overwritten in the last two lines hence the need to store values in a list and append.

You also cannot use tuples as you mentioned in your answer without creating new tuples each time you want to add a new value as tuples are **immutable**.

You can `print(dict(d))` or  use `pprint` if you don't want the `defaultdict(<class 'list'>,)`

```
from pprint import pprint as pp

pp(d)
{'Adam': ['12', '34'],
 'Dave': ['23', '25'],
 'Jack': ['13']}
```

Comment: Oh great! Is there a way to print the dictionary without the defaultdict(<class 'list'>,) part out of the print when I display it out of the IDLE? @PadraicCunningham

Comment: do `d = dict(d)` to turn the result into an ordinary dictionary.

Comment: you can `print(dict(d))` if you really want to

Comment: Fantastic! @AnttiHaapala @PadraicCunningham! Thank you very very much! I have had such great difficulty in doing this task! The stackOverflow community is so helping! Thank you so very much! I shall ask questions here again if necessary!

Answer (score 3):

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(list)
with open("guesses.txt") as inf:
    for line in inf:
        name, score = line.split(":", 1)
        result[name].append(int(score))
```

which gets you

```
# result
{ "Dave": [23, 25], "Jack": [13], "Adam": [12, 34] }
```

Comment: I do not think that your answer is correct. It does not deal with the special fact that "Dave and Adam are separately the same people. Dave is Dave.T and Adam is Adam.G" ;) -- ha, this is fun.