# Dictionary keys in alphabetical order

Tags: python, dictionary, printing

In my previous question, I found out how to drag some of my co - worker's scores together in a dictionary in the post [Reading data separated by colon per line in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28385822/reading-data-separated-by-colon-per-line-in-python). 
Now, if I want to arrange the dictionary so that the keys are in order of name, so `Adam`, `Dave` and `Jack`'s scores would appear in that order.

I have used the method below:

```
sorted(self.docs_info.items)
```

But that returns nothing. I also want it to be returned to the IDLE in the format

```
Adam 12 34
Dave 25 23
Jack 13
```

I tried to use the `pprint` method, but that didn't work either. 
How can I fix this?

My previous code (finished) appeared like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
with open('guesses.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        name,val = line.split(":")
        d[name].append(int(val))
```

With Credit to Padraic Cunningham and Antti Haapala!

Comment: @Selcuk My apologies, but that does not answer the pprint method.

Comment: @DelbertJ.Nava Can you edit the problem to add the relevant code pieces around the `pprint` usage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just sort the keys and use the key to access the value:

```
for k in sorted(d):
    print(k,d[k])

Adam [12, 34]
Dave [23, 25]
Jack [13]
```

To get the strings use `str.join`:

```
for k in sorted(d):
    print(k," ".join(map(str,d[k])))

Adam 12 34
Dave 23 25
Jack 13
```

calling sorted on the dict is the same as calling sorted on `dict.keys()` so we just need to use the each now sorted key from the  list to access in the required order.

Comment: lol another downvote!

Comment: Doh, when did you do the edit with join/map/str? ;)

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke, a while ago ;)

Comment: I'll leave my solution, nevertheless. It has less dictionary lookups (not that this actually matters here...).

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke was just wrinting you took a different approach though using items, I was going to but took less typing using the key. Not sure which is actually more efficient

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Thanks again! Damn, this python language is really making my brain twist and turn!

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke Thanks! Don't worry, no messing with the Adam.G's now ;)

Comment: @DelbertJ.Nava, no prob. It will get easier ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> for name, values in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[0]):
...     print("%s %s" % (name, " ".join(map(str, values))))
...
Adam 12 34
Dave 25 23
Jack 13
```